# What causes Assertion Error during EXPORT of glTF

Tags: export

I have a model I have created and when I select EXPORT > glTF I get an error 'Assertion error'.
What could be causing this and what do I need to do to fix the problem? I feel that perhaps there may be another step I need to do before exporting but searching Youtube tutorial and looking in the manual I cannot determine what that step(s) are. I have the addon Import Export: Maps Models Importer installed and enabled.
Here is the output text -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried using Export to Extended glTF 2.0 (glb/gltf) for MSFS and that completes succesfully so my work is complete.
I did also try exporting to obj and also fbx which works ok so I am assuming it is a bug when attempting to export to a 'normal' glTF.